# Python networkx function to_latex_raw problems with node_options

Tags: python, package, latex, networkx, tikz

I am trying to automatically generate LaTeX Code with Python. For that I wanted to use the package networkx, because it has the great function `to_latex_raw`. My problem is, that I don't quite understand the option `node_option`. I don't see any difference when using it. I have the folvogin line of code:

```
nx.to_latex_raw(G, 
                           tikz_options='scale = 3, font= \Large', 
                           node_options='circle, draw',
                           default_node_options='circle, draw=blue', 
                           pos=layout, 
                           node_label = node_labels, 
                           edge_label=labels, 
                           default_edge_options = "bend left=30")
```

I generate a tikzpicture and I want to have every node as a circle. With `default_node_option` it does not work and with `node_option` I don't get a different result. Can someone help me?

Here is the full code:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import string

def draw_graph(adj_matrix):
    n = len(adj_matrix)
    G = nx.DiGraph(np.matrix(adj_matrix))
    labels = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[0:n]
    node_labels = {i: labels[i] for i in range(0,n)}
    layout = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=1)
    labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
    # to_latex_raw(G, pos='pos', tikz_options='', default_node_options='', node_options='node_options', node_label='label', 
    # default_edge_options='', edge_options='edge_options', edge_label='label', edge_label_options='edge_label_options')
    return nx.to_latex_raw(G, 
                           tikz_options='scale = 3, font= \Large', 
                           node_options='circle, draw',
                           default_node_options='shape=circle,draw=blue,fill=blue!20!', 
                           pos=layout, 
                           node_label = node_labels, 
                           edge_label=labels, 
                           default_edge_options = "bend left=30") 

adj_matrix = [
    [0, 2, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0]
]

print("\\section{The First}\n")
print((draw_graph(adj_matrix)))
```